# SPARQL-queries (HELP!)

Tags: ontology, owl, protege

So, I have an [Ontology](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=17434206222510754967) and need some help with my SPARQL-queries. 
The ontology is based on different beer ingredients and equipment for brewing. 
For instance, it has the class "Ingredients", and a subclass "Malt/Grain", and then a subclass "Dark". Now I have some different, more specific types of dark malts, that are individuals, and members of the class Dark.

If I go into one individual in Protege, for instance "Dark_Crystal", will have "Dark" under its field of "Types"

So, I want to be able to ask queries like: "Show me all dark malts" "Show me the malt "Dark_Crystal", and if not in stock show alternative malts of the same type.
I´m not too good with SPARQL as much time have gone un to the ontology. I know a little, but I just don´t know how I would formulate it, or which tags that should define them.

This is my poor shot at a query, I just don´t know how i would formulate it right.

```
SELECT ?Malt WHERE
{
?malt rdfs:subClassOf [
    owl:someValuesFrom :Dark

}
```

Thanks a lot guys, hope I explained it well enough and that some of you may have some examples.

Comment: Is it SPARQL you're trying to use here? SPARQL-DL?

Comment: Also it would help if you were showing the ontology you were using.

Comment: Did you manage to sort your problem out?

Comment: Now I have shown the ontology that I am using. And it is SPARQL I am trying to use, yes, I have edited the thread a little. I´m still struggling a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test because I do not have your ontology but on the top of my head, that's how I would do it:

If `Dark` is a literal:

```
SELECT ?malt WHERE
{
?malt :hasColor "Dark"
}
```

If `Dark` is a class:

```
SELECT ?malt WHERE
{
?malt :hasColor ?color.
?color rdf:type :Dark
}
```

Comment: Sure, you can do this with `rdfs:domain` and `rdfs:range` but you don't have to. If you're speaking of speaking of declaring an instance, you just neef the following two statements:

`3

Comment: You can use RDFS for this with the properties `rdfs:domain` and `rdfs:range`, but you do not have to. These properties will just be used in your inferring engine to infer the type of an individual if it is not declared.

If you're asking about the individual declaration, you have to do it, as follows (N-Turtle syntax):

`#Dark_Malt rdfs:subClassOf #Malt`
`#Muntons_Dark rdf:type #Dark_Malt`